# How does one break out strings of multiple key value pairs in a single dataframe column into a new dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pulling data from a sql database into a pandas dataframe. The dataframe is a single column containing various quantities of key value pairs stored in a string. I would like to make a new dataframe that contains two columns, one holding the keys, and the other holding the values.

The dataframe looks like:

```
In[1]:
print(df.tail())

Out[1]:
WK_VAL_PAIRS
166  {('sloth', 0.073), ('animal', 0.034), ('gift', 0.7843)}                              
167  {('dabbing', 0.0863), ('gift', 0.7843)}      
168  {('grandpa', 0.0156), ('funny', 1.3714), ('grandfather', 0.0015)}                                     
169  {('nerd', 0.0216)}
170  {('funny', 1.3714), ('pineapple', 0.0107)}
```

Ideally, the new dataframe would look like:

```
0  |  sloth    |  0.073
1  |  animal   |  0.034
2  |  gift     |  0.07843
3  |  dabbing  |  0.0863
4  |  gift     |  0.7843
...
etc.
```

I have been successful in separating out the key value pairs from a single row into a dataframe, as show below. From here it will be trivial to split out the pairs into thier own columns.

```
In[2]:
def prep_text(row):
    string = row.replace('{', '')
    string = string.replace('}', '')
    string = string.replace('\',', '\':')
    string = string.replace(' ', '')
    string = string.replace(')', '')
    string = string.replace('(', '')
    string = string.replace('\'', '')
    return string

df['pairs'] = df['WK_VAL_PAIRS'].apply(prep_text)
dd = df['pairs'].iloc[166]
af = pd.DataFrame([dd.split(',') for x in dd.split('\n')])
af.transpose()

Out[2]:

0   sloth:0.073
1   animal:0.034
2   gift:0.7843
3   spirit:0.0065
4   fans:0.0093
5   funny:1.3714
```

However, I'm missing the leap to apply this transformation to the entire dataframe. Is there a way to do this with an `.apply()` style function, rather than a `for each` loop. What is the most pythonic way of handling this?

Any help would be appreciated.

### Solution

With Chris's strong hint below, I was able to get to an adequate solution for my needs:

```
def prep_text(row):
    string = row.replace('\'', '')
    string = '"'+ string + '"'
    return string


kvp_df = pd.DataFrame(
                        re.findall(
                            '(\w+), (\d.\d+)', 
                            df['WK_VAL_PAIRS'].apply(prep_text).sum()
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: Whelp, what is outputting that? Why isn't it JSON (or some other standard format)? Is this being stored in the database or did you create this somehow?

Comment: That is how it is stored in the database. It is being loaded into a dataframe using ```pd.read_sql()```.

Comment: Whelp, I recommend not storing it in the database in that format (use JSON instead)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `re.findall` with `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

s = pd.Series(["{(stepper, 0.0001), (bob, 0.0017), (habitual, 0.0), (line, 0.0097)}",
"{(pete, 0.01), (joe, 0.0019), (sleep, 0.0), (cline, 0.0099)}"])

pd.DataFrame(re.findall('(\w+), (\d.\d+)', s.sum()))
```

Output:

```
          0       1
0   stepper  0.0001
1       bob  0.0017
2  habitual     0.0
3      line  0.0097
4      pete    0.01
5       joe  0.0019
6     sleep     0.0
7     cline  0.0099
```

Comment: That's slick, Chris. Now I just to implement it over the entire dataframe.